# What exactly is the difference between 'Lambda formats'?

Tags: python, object, lambda, argument-passing

First of all, I'm a begginer in Python, so get ready for a nooby question ))

In one of the topics on this site I've found quite a useful piece of advice concerning the use of lambda function.

Here's my code before correcting:

```
def entree1(self):                    #function that is supposed to change text in 
self.configure(text = "X")              the label block from whatever it is to 'X'

fen = Tk()

pole1 = Label(fen, text = '|_|')
pole1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda: entree1(pole1))         #event handler reffering to the function above
```

Here's my code after correcting:

```
def entree1(self):                    #function that is supposed to change text in 
self.configure(text = "X")              the label block from whatever it is to 'X'

fen = Tk()

pole1 = Label(fen, text = '|_|')
pole1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: entree1(pole1))          #event handler reffering to the function above
```

In a nutshell I changed **lambda: some func** to **lambda x: some func**.

And it worked, which is great, although I can't figure out the difference between this two variants.
Could you please tell me what exactly changed after I added **x**?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me translate lambda expressions to function definitions that you are probably more used to:

```
lambda : entree1(pole1)
```

is the same as

```
def lambdaFunc():
    global pole1
    return entree1(pole1)
```

Your corrected function is

```
lambda x : entree1(pole1)
```

which is the same as

```
def lambdaFunc(x):
    global pole1
    return entree1(pole1)
```

You need the extra argument because Tk buttons call the function they are bound to with a variable (I forget what the variable is, exactly), therefore calling a function with an input variable when it doesn't take one causes errors.

Comment: The `global` declarations of `pole1` are superfluous.

Comment: ah, ok, I think I get it. It still remains a rather weird concept for me, but I think the true understanding will come with time. Thank you very much!